# Endless 'The thread 0x2cf0 has exited with code 0 (0x0)' when I run Sendinblue (brevo) email sending code

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, sendinblue

I have a class named BrevoEmailSender which functions to send transactional email using the Brevo (previously named Sendinblue) [See Here.](https://developers.brevo.com/reference/sendtransacemail).

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using sib_api_v3_sdk.Api;
using sib_api_v3_sdk.Client;
using sib_api_v3_sdk.Model;
 
namespace XYZproject.Services
{

  public class BrevoEmailSender
  {
    public void main()
    {

        Configuration.Default.ApiKey.Add("api-key", "xkeysib-xxx");

        var apiInstance = new TransactionalEmailsApi();

        string SenderName = "J";
        string SenderEmail = "j@gmail.com";
        SendSmtpEmailSender Email = new SendSmtpEmailSender(SenderName, SenderEmail);

        string ToEmail = "w@gmail.com";
        string ToName = "W";
        SendSmtpEmailTo smtpEmailTo = new SendSmtpEmailTo(ToEmail, ToName);

        List<SendSmtpEmailTo> To = new List<SendSmtpEmailTo>();
        To.Add(smtpEmailTo);

        string BccName = "J";
        string BccEmail = "j@gmail.com";
        SendSmtpEmailBcc BccData = new SendSmtpEmailBcc(BccEmail, BccName);
        List<SendSmtpEmailBcc> Bcc = new List<SendSmtpEmailBcc>();
        Bcc.Add(BccData);

        string CcName = "J";
        string CcEmail = "j@gmail.com";
        SendSmtpEmailCc CcData = new SendSmtpEmailCc(CcEmail, CcName);
        List<SendSmtpEmailCc> Cc = new List<SendSmtpEmailCc>();
        Cc.Add(CcData);

        string HtmlContent = "<html><body><h1>This is my first transactional email {{params.parameter}}</h1> Try link <a href=google.com>a</a> </body></html>";
        string TextContent = null;
        string Subject = "My {{params.subject}}";
        string ReplyToName = "J";
        string ReplyToEmail = "j";
        SendSmtpEmailReplyTo ReplyTo = new SendSmtpEmailReplyTo(ReplyToEmail, ReplyToName);
        string AttachmentUrl = null;
        string stringInBase64 = "aGVsbG8gdGhpcyBpcyB0ZXN0";
        byte[] Content = System.Convert.FromBase64String(stringInBase64);
        string AttachmentName = "test.txt";
        SendSmtpEmailAttachment AttachmentContent = new SendSmtpEmailAttachment(AttachmentUrl, Content, AttachmentName);
        List<SendSmtpEmailAttachment> Attachment = new List<SendSmtpEmailAttachment>();
        Attachment.Add(AttachmentContent);
        JObject Headers = new JObject();
        Headers.Add("Some-Custom-Name", "unique-id-1234");
        long? TemplateId = null;
        JObject Params = new JObject();
        Params.Add("parameter", "Some Parameter Here");
        Params.Add("subject", "Title Of Email");
        List<string> Tags = new List<string>();
        Tags.Add("mytag");
        SendSmtpEmailTo1 smtpEmailTo1 = new SendSmtpEmailTo1(ToEmail, ToName);
        List<SendSmtpEmailTo1> To1 = new List<SendSmtpEmailTo1>();
        To1.Add(smtpEmailTo1);
        Dictionary<string, object> _parmas = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        _parmas.Add("params", Params);
        SendSmtpEmailReplyTo1 ReplyTo1 = new SendSmtpEmailReplyTo1(ReplyToEmail, ReplyToName);
        SendSmtpEmailMessageVersions messageVersion = new SendSmtpEmailMessageVersions(To1, _parmas, null, Cc, ReplyTo1, Subject);
        List<SendSmtpEmailMessageVersions> messageVersiopns = new List<SendSmtpEmailMessageVersions>();
        messageVersiopns.Add(messageVersion);

        try
        {
            var sendSmtpEmail = new SendSmtpEmail(Email, To, Bcc, Cc, HtmlContent, TextContent, Subject, ReplyTo, Attachment, Headers, TemplateId, Params, messageVersiopns, Tags);
            CreateSmtpEmail result = apiInstance.SendTransacEmail(sendSmtpEmail);
            Debug.WriteLine(result.ToJson());
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToJson());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }


}
}
```

In my Program.cs, I have this line:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<BrevoEmailSender, BrevoEmailSender>();
```

In my controller, I call 'Main' like this:

```
private readonly BrevoEmailSender _brevoEmailSender;

public XyzController(BrevoEmailSender brevoEmailSender)
    {
        _brevoEmailSender = brevoEmailSender;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(string? submitButton = "")
    {
        if (submitButton == "submit")
        {
             _brevoEmailSender.main();
        }
        
        return View();
    }
```

When I run this, the email was send. The problem is, I have this endless thread running. It keeps running on the line ' _brevoEmailSender.main(); ' in my controller. Here is the thread.

```
{
"messageIds": [
"<202308141331.52058931286.1@smtp-relay.mailin.fr>"
]
}
The thread 0x2cf0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x50d4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4a0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x147c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1a00 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x53a4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4978 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4fa8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1198 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
.
.
.
```

I read in many solutions here that this thread is not a problem, but in my case it is, as it goes on endlessly. Any idea how to solve this?